# A word between 'adjusted' and 'tampered with'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that doesn't sound as precise or intentional as 'adjusted', but doesn't have the accusative connotations as 'tampered'.

Example sentence:

> The mechanic installed new struts on the car, but now the steering is out of alignment. I can't imagine why they would tamper with/adjust the steering.

I think 'adjust' in this sentence is wrong because it implies intentionally making something more exact, eg: 'I adjusted the temperature setting to make the room more comfortable'.

I think 'tamper' implies purposely, and perhaps nefariously, making something worse or dangerous, eg: 'The police found that the ATM had been tampered with'.

Is there a word in between these two?

Comment: In your example with the mechanic, and similar ones with plumbers etc..(or parents?) .. I would say "touch". as in I can't imagine why they would even touch the steering systems.

Comment: continuing on "touch".. more formally might be "involve themselves with" or "get involved with" etc.

Comment: _Change_ (or _alter_) seems like a good, neutral word to use here.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to remove the intentionality aspect altogether (it could have been an inadvertent side-effect): 'I can't see why the steering should be/have been affected.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - ***affected*** is what I thought of as well.

Comment: A slang term for that is **mess with** (...why would they mess with the steering?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word you need is ***interfere***.

***I can't imagine why they would interfere with the steering***.